# Close current form and open a different one in Access?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to create a macro that closes the current form and opens the main form.

Since I have so many forms and I need the same button with this macro in all of them, I want to create a macro just once and not for each form separately.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you're trying to do. Can you provide an example or better explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a code module and add the following function:

```
Public Sub CloseMeAndOpenMain(frmMe As Form)
    DoCmd.Close acForm, frmMe.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain" 'Replace this with the actual name of your Main form
End Sub
```

Now, each time you have a button that should close the current form and open the "frmMain" form, you would write the click event handler like so:

```
Private Sub btnCloseForm_Click()
    CloseMeAndOpenMain Me
End Sub
```

`Me` is a reference to the current form, and each form has a `Name` property.  Therefore you can write a function to close it without having to hardcode the name as a String (except of course for the main form).